# angular broadcast data to directive from external file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to pass data from an external js file to a directive angular file.
Here is what I'm doing.

On my external js file:

```
var formatData = {
    id: 1,
    state: 'moving'
}    
angular.element(document).scope().$broadcast('sendData', formatData);
```

In my directive:

```
scope.$on('API.sendData', function(formatData) { 
    console.dir(formatData);
});
```

What get's logged:
[image]

Help?

Comment: can you do this console.dir(arguments) instead of  console.dir(formatData);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the second parameter of the listener function, first one is the event data.

```
scope.$on('API.sendData', function(event, formatData) { 
    console.dir(formatData);
});
```

hope this helps.